# Compute correlation between features and target variable

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, correlation

What is the best solution to compute correlation between my features and target variable ?? My dataframe have 1000 rows and 40 000 columns...

Exemple :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 4 ,6], [1, 3, 4, 7], [4, 6, 8, 12], [5, 3, 2 ,10]], columns=['Feature1', 'Feature2','Feature3','Target'])
```

This code works fine but this is too long on my dataframe ... I need only the last column of correlation matrix : correlation with target (not pairwise feature corelation).

```
corr_matrix=df.corr()
corr_matrix["Target"].sort_values(ascending=False)
```

The **np.corcoeff()** function works with array but can we exclude the pairwise feature correlation ?

Comment: For a better answer look here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39137/how-can-i-check-the-correlation-between-features-and-target-variable

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use pandas `corr` on each column:

```
df.drop("Target", axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.corr(df.Target))
```

Comment: Exactly what I need !

Answer (score 20):

Since Pandas 0.24 released in January 2019, you can simply use [`DataFrame.corrwith()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html):

```py
df.corrwith(df["Target"])
```

Comment: How can we plot this correlation array as a heatmap?

Answer (score 2):

You can use scipy.stats.pearsonr on each of the feature columns like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

# example data
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 4 ,6], [1, 3, 4, 7], [4, 6, 8, 12], [5, 3, 2 ,10]],
                  columns=['Feature1', 'Feature2','Feature3','Target'])

# Only compute pearson prod-moment correlations between feature
# columns and target column
target_col_name = 'Target'
feature_target_corr = {}
for col in df:
    if target_col_name != col:
        feature_target_corr[col + '_' + target_col_name] = \
            pearsonr(df[col], df[target_col_name])[0]
print("Feature-Target Correlations")
print(feature_target_corr)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 4 ,6], [1, 3, 4, 7], [4, 6, 8, 12], [5, 3, 2 ,10]], columns=['Feature1', 'Feature2','Feature3','Target'])
```

For correlation between your target variable and all other features:

```
df.corr()['Target']
```

This works in my case. Let me know if any corrections/updates on the same.

To get any conclusive results your instance should be atleast 10 times your number of features.

Comment: This will compute unnecessarily the correlation between all columns.  Instead you should use `df.corrwith(df['target'])`